# XML error in my netbeans project

Tags: java, xml, macos, netbeans

I transfered my game project from windows machine to mac and when I opened the project it gave me an error which I am not able to resolve.
errors look something like this:

```
/Users/dinajam/NetBeansProjects/Flip Flop/build.xml:12: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/dinajam/NetBeansProjects/Flip Flop/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Tomorrow is my project submission and i have to present using mac.

Comment: Sounds like a UTF-8 byte-order-mark issue.

Comment: You change OS, don't think : surely a encoding problem. 

Open the build-impl.xml file, if you have strange characters at the beginning of the file, try to retrieve the original file and format it in UTF-8 before using that on your Mac.

Comment: Hy! yes i already checked that keenly by myself by found nothing unusual there in build.xml file

Comment: "try to retrieve the original file and format it in UTF-8 before using that on your Mac"   i didnt get that